# Delete cell and the corresponding image from UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a horizontal `UICollectionView` with a custom `UICollectionViewCell`. Each cell has a `UIImageView` that shows the images that the user has selected. 
Now, what I want to do is to add a delete button (or Image?) in the corner of each cell and when it's clicked, it deletes the corresponding image from the array and the cell itself. I have 2 questions:

1. How to add that button/image functionality programmatically (I don't want to mess with the storyboard really)
2. How to implement the deletion functionality from the corresponding `UIViewController`?

The

Something like this:

[image]

Here's my Custom Cell class:

```
class PhotoCell: UICollectionViewCell, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var cellImage: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupUI()
    }

    func setupUI()
    {
        cellImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cellImage.clipsToBounds = true
        cellImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    }
}
```

Here's the code of the entire View Controller

```
   import UIKit
    import SDWebImage
    import Photos
    import AssetsPickerViewController
    import SVProgressHUD

    class PhotoVC: UIViewController
    {
        // MARK: IBOutlets
        @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
        @IBOutlet weak var postButton: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var userProfileImage: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var userUsername: UsernameLabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var postTitleTextField: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var postContentTextField: UITextView!
        @IBOutlet weak var postTagsTextField: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var postSourceTextField: UITextField!

        // MARK: Class Properties
        var user: UserModel!
        var post: Post!
        var cameraPhotoUIImage: UIImage?
        var assets = [PHAsset]()
        lazy var assetsTurnedIntoImages =
        {
            return  [UIImage]()
        }()

        lazy var imageManager = {
            return PHCachingImageManager()
        }()

        // MARK: View Did Load
        override func viewDidLoad()
        {
            self.assetsTurnedIntoImages = [UIImage](repeating: UIImage(), count: assets.count) // Important! make sure to have enough pre-created space in the array
            super.viewDidLoad()
            setupCollectionView()
        }

        // MARK: View Did Appear
        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated)
            fetchUserUsernameAndProfileImage()
            userProfileImageSetup()
            handlePostButtonState()
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }

        // MARK: View Will Disappear
        override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
            emptyArrays()
         }

        // MARK: Fetch User Username And Profile Photo
        func fetchUserUsernameAndProfileImage()
        {
            Api.User.observeCurrentUser
            { (userModel) in
                self.user = userModel
                self.userUsername.text = userModel.username_lowercase!
                if let userProfileImageURL = URL(string: userModel.profileImageUrlString!)
                {
                    self.userProfileImage.sd_setImage(with: userProfileImageURL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "default_profileHeader"))
                }
            }
        }

        // MARK: Cancel Pressed
        @IBAction func cancelPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
        {
            emptyArrays()
            collectionView.reloadData()
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        // MARK: Post Pressed
        @IBAction func postPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
        {
            guard let title = postTitleTextField.text else { return }
            guard let content = postContentTextField.text else { return }
            guard let tags = postTagsTextField.text else { return }
            guard let source = postSourceTextField.text else { return }

            view.endEditing(true)
            SVProgressHUD.setDefaultMaskType(.gradient)
            SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Posting...")
            print("Assets turned into images before posting is:", assetsTurnedIntoImages.count)
            if let takenImage = cameraPhotoUIImage
            {
                let imageToUpload = takenImage

                if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToUpload, 0.1)
                {
                    let ratio: [CGFloat] = [imageToUpload.size.width / imageToUpload.size.height]
                    DatabaseService.uploadDataToServer(data: imageData, videoUrl: nil, multipleImages: nil, ratio: ratio, title: title, content: content, tags: tags, source: source,
                                                       onSuccess:
                                                       {
                                                            self.clean()
                                                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Segue_PhotoPostToTabbar, sender: nil)
                                                       })
                }
            }
            else if assetsTurnedIntoImages.count > 0
            {
                DatabaseService.uploadDataToServer(data: nil, videoUrl: nil, multipleImages: assetsTurnedIntoImages, ratio: nil, title: title, content: title, tags: tags, source: source,
                                                   onSuccess:
                                                   {
                                                    self.clean()
                                                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Segue_PhotoPostToTabbar, sender: nil)
                                                   })
            }
            else
            {
                SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: "At least 1 photo is required to make this post.")
            }
        }

        @IBAction func settingsPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
        {
            //TODO: Work on settings for the post
        }

        // MARK: End Editing
        override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
        {
            view.endEditing(true)
        }

        // MARK: Clean Text Fields And Arrays
        func clean()
        {
            postTitleTextField.text = ""
            postTagsTextField.text = ""
            postContentTextField.text = ""
            postSourceTextField.text = ""
            emptyArrays()
        }

        // MARK: Empty Arrays
        func emptyArrays()
        {
            assets.removeAll()
            assetsTurnedIntoImages.removeAll()
            cameraPhotoUIImage = nil
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }

        // MARK: Handle Post Button State
        func handlePostButtonState()
        {
            if cameraPhotoUIImage != nil || assets.count > 0
            {
                postButton.isEnabled = true
            }
            else
            {
                postButton.isEnabled = false
            }
        }

        // MARK: User Profile UI Update
        func userProfileImageSetup()
        {
            userProfileImage.layer.cornerRadius = userProfileImage.frame.size.width / 2
            userProfileImage.clipsToBounds = true
        }

    }

    // MARK: Collectionew View Delegate & Datasourse
    extension PhotoVC : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate
    {
        func setupCollectionView()
        {
            collectionView.dataSource = self
            collectionView.delegate = self
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
        {
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotoPostCVCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoPostCVCell
                if let takenImage = cameraPhotoUIImage
                {
                    cell.cellImage.image = takenImage
                }
                if assets.count > 0
                {
                    let asset = assets[indexPath.row]

                    var imageRequestOptions: PHImageRequestOptions
                    {
                        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
                        options.version = .current
                        options.resizeMode = .exact
                        options.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
                        options.isSynchronous = true
                        return options
                    }
                    // TODO: Fix the size of the images. Right now it's 500x500
                    let targetSize = CGSize(width: 500, height: 500)
                    imageManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: imageRequestOptions)
                    { (image, info) in
                        if image != nil
                        {
                            print(image!.size)
                            cell.cellImage.image = image
                            self.assetsTurnedIntoImages[indexPath.row] = image!
                            cell.deleteButton?.tag = indexPath.row
                            cell.deleteButton?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.deleteImage(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
                        }
                    }
                }
                return cell
        }

        @objc func deleteImage(sender:UIButton) {
            let i = sender.tag
            print(i)
            assetsTurnedIntoImages.remove(at: i)
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
        {
            if assetsTurnedIntoImages.count > 0
            {
                return assetsTurnedIntoImages.count
            }
            else
            {
                return 1
            }
        }

        // MARK: Preview Selected Image
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
        {
            let postStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: Storyboard_Post, bundle:nil)

            if let destinationVC = postStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PreviewImageVC") as? PreviewImageVC
            {
                destinationVC.allowedDismissDirection = .both
                destinationVC.maskType = .clear
                if cameraPhotoUIImage != nil
                {
                    destinationVC.transferedImageToPreview = cameraPhotoUIImage!
                    destinationVC.showInteractive()
                }
                if assetsTurnedIntoImages.count > 0
                {
                    destinationVC.transferedImageToPreview = assetsTurnedIntoImages[indexPath.row]
                    destinationVC.showInteractive()
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you have CollectionView then you can easily manage by storyboard or xib  just take one array of imageView and manage it by collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int)

Comment: That won't help when I don't have the button in place really. And I also mentioned I'm not sure how to do that as well

Comment: @Dani for delete functionality set button.tag = indexpath.row and addTarget:action:forControlEvents  in collectionviewcellforrowatindexpath method then delete that indexpath item in collectionview using button addaction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is quite easy to accomplish. Add a `UIButton` to your cell xib in the top left corner which only partially overlaps with your image view. Add constraints. Then connect outlet for this button to your cell class: call it `deleteButton`.

You can set the image for the button in storyboard to this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGpjY.png.

The code can then be as follows:

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
 
    @IBOutlet weak var deleteButton: UIButton!
    
}
```

And in the collection view controller:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? CustomCell else { return UICollectionViewCell() }
    cell.deleteButton?.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.deleteButton?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteUser(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    // Do other cell setup here with data source
    return cell
}

@objc func deleteUser(sender:UIButton) {
    let i = sender.tag
    dataSource.remove(at: i)
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Here, `dataSource` is your model array for populating each cell.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm testing your code, but the issue that I see is that when I try to delete something it always removes the last item (image) in the array, not the selected index. Also, If I remove all of the items at the array, its basically goes out of range and crashes

Comment: @Dani ok. have edited the answer with a different approach. let me know if it works for you. :)

Comment: Ah, still doing the same thing. I also tried with                         `cell.deleteButton?.tag = indexPath.row - 1`  but that's not even close. I'm not sure why it's not working. It literally removes the last item of the array, not the selected one. Despite which cell's delete button you tap (whether first or somewhere in the middle, always deletes the last item)

Comment: add a breakpoint in the deleteUser function, what is sender.tag at that point?

Comment: also what is your data source? an array?

Comment: The `sender.tag` is 1, when I click the second cell delete button, which is correct. And yes, it's an array of `UIImage`

Comment: I've added some additional code, because maybe there's an issue there? I'm not sure really.

Comment: please post the full code, so i can help better. currently i cant see whats the issue.

Comment: I've added the entire View Controller. Please, see the updated code.

Comment: thanks, that helps a bit. What is `assetsTurnedIntoImages` when you set the button tag?

Comment: I selected 5 images and it showed that `assetsTurnedIntoImages.count ` is 5. When I deleted one, it showed 4.

Answer (score 1):

Hello here are the two classes as a demo (excuse the lazy code)

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    var dataForDemo = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataForDemo.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionCell
        cell.myTitlteLabel.text = String(dataForDemo[indexPath.item])

        cell.callback = callbackForCell() // option callback
//        cell.buttonX.tag = indexPath.item  // option button tag
        return cell
    }

    func callbackForCell() -> ((MyCollectionCell)->Void){ // option callback
        return { [weak self] cell in
            guard let `self` = self else { return }
            guard let index = self.myCollectionView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }

            self.dataForDemo.remove(at: index.item)
            self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) { // option button tag
//        self.dataForDemo.remove(at: sender.tag)
//        self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

and the cell class:

```
class MyCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var callback : ((MyCollectionCell)->Void)?  // option callback
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonX: UIButton!   // option button tag
    @IBOutlet weak var myTitlteLabel: UILabel!
    @IBAction func removeButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        callback?(self)
    }
}
```

The storyboard looks like so:

[image]

So here are two options on how you an do this. One is with callback and the other with tag on button.

Personally I prefer the one with callback block.

Comment: I tested your method as well. I achieved the same result as with the one suggested by Pravan above. For some reason, neither the callback method nor the button.tag one works for me. It always deletes the last item of the array, despite which delete button you tap on